Solving a system with two quadratic forms
for a research project I need to solve a system of equations of the following form:
\begin{align*}
x^\textsf{T} A x &= \beta \\ 
x^\textsf{T} B x &= \beta,
\end{align*}
where $x \in \mathbb R^N$ is situated on the unit sphere and $A$ and $B$ are real symmetric matrices (both matrices and $\beta$ are given).
To be more specific, the quadratic equations here are of the following special form:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n,k,m,l} \lambda_{n,k,m,l} \Big(x_2(n,k) x_2(m,l) - x_1(n,k)x_1(m,l) \Big) &= \beta \\ 
\sum_{n,k,m,l} \lambda_{n,k,m,l} \Big(x_2(n,k) x_1(m,l) + x_1(n,k)x_2(m,l) \Big) &= \beta,\\ \\
\text{such that: } \quad \sum_{n,k} x_1(n,k)^2 + x_2(n,k)^2 &= 1,
\end{align*} where the index ranges are given by $n,m \in \{1,\ldots,K\}$; $k,l \in \{1,\ldots, N\}$. Numerically, we are able to find a solution, but I would like to show that we can always find a solution. Can anyone point me to a resource on this? or recognize this type of system equations? Thanks in advance :)

Simplifying you want to prove $x^T(A-B)x = 0$ always has a solution. Probably the answer will lie in the singular value decomposition of (A-B)

without any eigenvalues needed:  name $H=A-B$  and then use Sylvester's Law of Inertia   by solving $P^T HP =D$   diagonal for nonsingular $P$   as to how to do that, if you are not good at completing the square by hand, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr

Hi @DhanviSreenivasan , thanks for the reply, I also need to show that both expressions equal the given $\beta$.  So not only does $x^T (A - B) x^T = 0$ need a nontrivial solution, $x^T A x = \beta$ has to hold. This cannot be resolved by simply rescaling a given solution since I also require that $x$ is on the unit sphere :/ ( but thank you for pointing me to the SVD! I’ll look more closely in that direction.)

@WillJagy So what you suggest is to put the equation $x^T H x = 0$ in diagonal form? I don’t immediately see how that solves it for me, but it’s definitely a good first step to analyse what is going on.  Thank you !

The system of equations may have no solution. For example, $A$ is a positive diagonal matrix and $B = 2A$ (geometrically, the system is represented by two ellipsoids and the second one is contained inside the first one).

Geometrically, you are looking for intersection points of two ellipsoids (assume A, B are positive definite) and the unit sphere. Clearly, this depends on A, B and $\beta$
